# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-typescript, conditional-rendering

I've got a useState variable that's grabbing the value from a select input, and conditionally rendering a text component based on that. i.e, if they select other in the select input, a text input for other will appear. When I do that I'm getting this error:

[image: Code and error]

This is built in typescript, and I was wondering if anyone knows what's causing the error, and how to fix it. I'd really appreciate any recommendations or responses, I wanna get this cleaned up before monday!

The code is just a normal useState variable, but it's throwing an error within the file. Here's after all the imports where I initialize the component:

[image: initialization]

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.value` is not known, because either `e` or `e.target` is unknown, you can either create typings or `(e: any) => setMainContactValue(e.target.value)` or `(e) => setMainContactValue(e.target.value as string)`

Comment: (e: any) throws an error, but setMainContactValue(e.target.value as string) built well, I appreciate it man!